# Stop python from replacing the wrong text

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to properly end off an .mp3 link but also stop the replacements function from replacing the wrong part of the link which is obviously causing it not to work.

```
data = pd.read_csv("output9.csv")

replacements = {'.mp3':'.mp3"'',} #works fine
```

But also makes the very same hyperlink not work through the insertion of the "

```
https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3"/dovetail.prxu.org/criminal/85cd4e4d-fa8b-4df2-8a8c-78ad0e800574/Episode_116_190504_audition_mix_neg18_part_1.mp3
```

How could I set the 2nd line as an exclusion? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: your best bet is to use regex here so you can specify exactly what strings you want to replace

Comment: It seems need replace only last `.mp3` by `.mp3"`  by `re.sub(r'\.mp3$', r'\.mp3"', link)` - but if add `"` also get invalid link. Can you explain more, why need `"` there?

Comment: @jezrael It's so it can tie off the other end of a <href=" link so the rest of the script can successfully pull the code out of inbetween the two " ". Then the python plugin xmbcswift2 can send it to be played (for a Kodi addon)

Comment: So `link = re.sub(r'\.mp3$', r'\.mp3"', link)` workink nice, like you need?

Comment: Or if need only add `"` to end why not use `link = link + '"'` or `link += '"'`?

Comment: What do the target strings look like before you apply the replacements?

Comment: @JackFleeting Like this:
of the...'}",https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/dovetail.prxu.org/criminal/85cd4e4d-fa8b-4df2-8a8c-78ad0e800574/Episode_116_190504_audition_mix_neg18_part_1.mp3
1,115,e

- obviously it's buried in text for the episode summary and the start of the new stuff for the next episode

Comment: @jezrael those look great but I've got no idea how to use them

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can do it in two steps; importantly - no regex; search around and you'll see that, if at all possible, regex should be avoided when dealing with html:

```
my_str = "https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/dovetail.prxu.org/criminal/85cd4e4d-fa8b-4df2-8a8c-78ad0e800574/Episode_116_190504_audition_mix_neg18_part_1.mp3"

my_str = my_str.replace('.mp3/','xxx').replace('.mp3','.mp3"').replace('xxx','.mp3/')

my_str
```

Output:

> 'https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/dovetail.prxu.org/criminal/85cd4e4d-fa8b-4df2-8a8c-78ad0e800574/Episode_116_190504_audition_mix_neg18_part_1.mp3"'